# Why does SDI flowgraph fails when filter in projection is introduced?

Tags: hana

I am developing a flowgraph in native HANA and I am receiving an error ORA-00972 after I have introduced a filter to the projection node that contains single quote sign.

The filter is as follows:

```
"VALID_FROM" >= to_timestamp(to_nvarchar($$MaxDT$$),'yyyymmddhh24miss')
```

When I change the filter to e.g:

```
"ID" IN (1,5,6,7,34)
```

it's working just fine.

I had the same error previously while i was querying a virtual table. The solution there was to make the namespace much much smaller so that namespace+table name+field name does not exceed 30 characters. But I am not sure what is the solution when this error is there in the flowgraph.

Any help appreciated!
Cheers

Comment: There is also one weird thing.. When i combine two filters from my post above with "and" it works perfectly fine..

Answer (score 0):

The error message is not from HANA but from an Oracle DB.

ORA-00972 means “Identifier too long” - so it may well be that the single-quoted string from the filter condition is mis-interpreted as an identifier in the remote Oracle DB.
Try to escape the single quote by using two consecutive singe quotes ''.

```
"VALID_FROM" >= to_timestamp(to_nvarchar($$MaxDT$$),''yyyymmddhh24miss'')
```

Also, reconsider the actual data type of VALID_FROM - it looks as if a character input get converted to mvarchar and then to timestamp.

Comment: Thanks for reply Lars. I have tried this as well yesterday, but that gives following error: sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near "yyyymmddhh24miss". When it comes to that input parameter it's actually a BIG INT. Client did already that parameter file, so i just had to cast it to a date for the where clause

Comment: I’d check the generated SQL for this remote table.

Comment: Can you explain how to do that Lars? We don't have access to the source system and i am not sure how to check it from WEBIDE.

Comment: I'm not sure where to find the statements in the WebIDE - usually I look at those either in HANA Studio or via the M_REMOTE_STATEMENTS view (https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.05/en-US/20b9a2217519101483f6949244f55513.html).